# Need help in using .on in jquery so that it can work with dynamic data also

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a function "single_double_click"  and I am invoking the same via `$('#packagelisttable tr').single_double_click(fn)`, which works fine with static data.

However it is not responding when I am deploying the same application to work with dynamic data.
I tried using `.on` also as mentioned in several posts but then also no success.Please find the same below:

1. `$(#packagelisttable ).on('single_double_click', 'tr', fn)`
2. `$(document).on('single_double_click', 'packagelisttable tr', fn)`

I need to click on a row of table (`#packagelisttable`) and need to check whether it was a single or double click.

Please find the code which I am using:

```
jQuery.fn.single_double_click = function (single_click_callback, double_click_callback, timeout) {
    return this.each(function () {
        var clicks = 0,
            self = this;
        jQuery(this).click(function (event) {
            clicks++;
            if (clicks == 1) {
                setTimeout(function () {
                    if (clicks == 1) {
                        single_click_callback.call(self, event);
                    } else {
                        double_click_callback.call(self, event);
                    }
                    clicks = 0;
                }, timeout || 300);
            }
        });
    });
}

//$(#packagelisttable ).on('single_double_click', 'tr', function(){
//$(document).on('single_double_click', 'packagelisttable tr', function(){
// $('#packagelisttable tr').single_double_click(function () {
alert("Try double-clicking me!")
},
function () {
    alert("Double click detected")
});
```

Comment: thanks for the edit @Rory McCrossan

Comment: Is there any specific reason for not using the standard onclick, ondblclick events for this purpose?

Comment: Thnks for the reply @Thangadurai....i tried that also but it was not working fine in my code and always onclick was getting invoked.That is the reason why i used this function.

Answer (score 1):

The delegated event version of `on` is used for events, but `single_double_click` is not an event. It is a function.

**It is not possible to connect a jQuery plugin/function to a dynamically loaded elements *that way*.**

You *either* need to connect any new elements to your plugin after load, or change the plugin to use classes (e.g. `class="singleordouble"`) and use a delegated click event handler, or you can add a selector as an additional parameter and attach to a non-changing ancestor element (as Cerlin Boss demonstrates).

e.g.

```
    jQuery(document).on('click', '.singleordouble', function (event) {
```

But if you do that, using a plugin becomes pointless.

It is more flexible to generate your own custom click events, using the settimeout trick you already have.

Here is a full example using custom events: http://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/wjf829ap/2/

Run this code once anywhere:

```
// Listen for any clicks on the desired 
$(document).on('click', '.singleordouble', function (e) {
    var $this = $(this);
    var clicks = $this.data("clicks") || 0;
    // increment  click counter (from data stored against this element)
    $(this).data("clicks", ++clicks);
    // if we are on the first click, wait for a possible second click
    if (clicks == 1) {
        setTimeout(function () {
            var clicks = $this.data("clicks");
            if (clicks == 1) {
                $this.trigger("customsingleclick");
            } else {
                $this.trigger("customdoubleclick");
            }
            $this.data("clicks", 0);
        }, 300);
    }
});
```

It will generate custom events (called `customsingleclick` and `customdoubleclick in this example, but call them whatever you want).

You can then simply listen for these custom events:

```
$(document).on('customsingleclick', function(e){
    console.log("single click on " + e.target.id);
});

$(document).on('customdoubleclick', function(e){
    console.log("double click on " + e.target.id);
});
```

Or using delegated event handlers: http://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/wjf829ap/3/

```
$(document).on('customsingleclick', '.singleordouble', function(){
    console.log("single click on " + this.id);
});

$(document).on('customdoubleclick', '.singleordouble', function(){
    console.log("double click on " + this.id);
});
```

Comment: Hi @TrueBlueAussie thnks for the reply.Actually I am totally new to  jquery and not sure as to how to go with the approach of " change the plugin to use classes (e.g. class="singleordouble") and use a delegated click event handler.

e.g.

    jQuery(document).on('click', '.singleordouble', function (event) {"

So would request you to please help me in this also.

Comment: @nish: Have added full example using custom events. This is more flexible as your high-level code looks like any normal event handler.

Comment: Thnks a lot @TrueBlueAussie, for your help. Will try to understand and implement the same .

Comment: @nish: `Cerlin Boss` has a simpler change if you don't want to go that far in changing how you do it. Just attach to a non-dynamic ancestor and supply the selector (used for delegated event handling) as a third parameter. :)

Answer (score 0):

how about [this](http://jsfiddle.net/psu4895k/)

I have made some small changes to your code. Not sure if this will work for you.

I have added one more parameter which takes a selector. Please comment if you have any doubt.

```
jQuery.fn.single_double_click = function (selector, single_click_callback, double_click_callback, timeout) {
    return this.each(function () {
        var clicks = 0,
            self = this;
        jQuery(this).on('click', selector, function (event) {
            clicks++;
            if (clicks == 1) {
                setTimeout(function () {
                    if (clicks == 1) {
                        single_click_callback.call(self, event);
                    } else {
                        double_click_callback.call(self, event);
                    }
                    clicks = 0;
                }, timeout || 300);
            }
        });
    });
}
```

Usage :

```
$('#headmnu').single_double_click('li', 
function () {
    ; // not doing anything here
}, function () {
    alert('twice')
});
```

Here `li` is the child of the first jquery selector(`$('#headmnu')`) which is a `ul`

This will work with dynamically added elements also.

**UPDATE**

Just to clarify `$('#headmnu')` is a parent element of all `li`s.

I have used `event delegation` here to achieve this. Please refer the [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/on/#direct-and-delegated-events) for more info

Comment: Yep, this technique will work too. Best clarify why you attach to the `$('#headmnu')` element.

Comment: sorry that was the id of an element which i used in testing this (please check the html in the fiddle).

Comment: Sorry, I meant explain *why you are are connecting to a non-changing ancestor element* :)

Comment: oh my apologies, the technique which i have used is called [`event delegation`](http://api.jquery.com/on/#direct-and-delegated-events) where the event will be assigned to a parent

Comment: *Sigh*... *I* know that... I meant explain it in your answer :)

Comment: Thnks a lot @TrueBlueAussie and Cerlin Boss for your suggestions.I analyzed both of your replies and it helped me in resolving my issue :).

Answer (score -1):

I checked your code and if you have pasted, then you should also check

```
$(#packagelisttable ).on('single_double_click', 'tr', fn) // shold be
$('#packagelisttable').on('single_double_click', 'tr', fn)

$(document).on('single_double_click', 'packagelisttable tr', fn) // should be
$(document).on('single_double_click', '#packagelisttable tr', fn)
```

Comment: It is not just typos. `single_double_click` *is not an event*! This code would never work (unless you added those as custom events).